# Shutdown IPhone when an application hangs

Tags: iphone

My application hangs. Pressing the home button doesn't return to the springboard anymore. Additionally pressing the power button for 10 seconds doesn't turn the iphone off at all.

Is there any way to force a shutdown?

Comment: To any moderators that might read this comment: this seems to belong on Ask Differently. It is a high quality question, just not in the right site on the SE network.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1 - To 'Force Quit' an iPhone application, hold down the Home button for up to 5 seconds.

2 - To force a reset (in rare occassions when 1 does not work), hold down the Power and Home buttons together for 10 seconds.

(this is documented in a Apple Support article - http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1430)

Comment: For future references, the second one is called a "Hard Reset" and it basically clears your temporary files (almost like rebooting your computer). People don't realize phones need to be restarted also. This won't delete any important data, just files that aren't important. (Like if you are on the main screen or setting page of the app, etc. If you delete a file like that it will just bring you straight to the main screen and regenerate the file blank. This helps solve simple bugs.

Comment: Good to know that even after 5 years.

Answer (score 7):

To force shutdown the iPhone 3G, just press down the power button first, followed by the home button. Hold the 2 buttons down until your screen changes.

That's it... A simple, but undocumented solution. Oh well. So far my iPhone has crashed in a few ways and this worked all the time.

Comment: It is documented on Apple's website...

Answer (score 2):

If your application reproducibly hangs the phone, please file a bug report at bugreport.apple.com and attach a copy of your application.  This is something Apple would be very interested in debugging.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the idea of bringing Apple's attention to a bug like this if it doesn't fix this... however, it would need to be an Apple app for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone hanged during boot when it tried to reset & erase all the iphoe contents.

Following are the steps to get your iPhone booting in Recovery Mode:
Step 1: Before getting the iphone in recovery mode, Open iTunes on your MAC or PC & attach the cable to iPhone.
Step 2: Hold down the Power & Home buttom simultaneously until the screen changes (around 10 secs.).
Step 3: Release the Power Button and keep pressing the Home Button for at least 30 secs.

Folow the instructions on your iTunes to restore the firmware of iPhone.

Hope, that this solution works for all who had problems like me.
Thankfully my problem is Solved.

Comment: You don't need to restore your iPhone... to do this, it will erase all your data unless you back it up. It will work, but is overkill if you use your iPhone for more than just a phone, browser, camera, and media viewer.